# ASPxGridView DeleteRow not deleting on another control callback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

I'm using the DEVExpress's gridview and have this code that deletes the selected gridview row from another control's customcallback,

the line

> GridFrom.DeleteRow(int.Parse(rowKey[2]));

retrieves the correct visibleIndex but does not remove the row from the gridview. The databind also does not refreshes the gridview's data and it requires refreshing of the page for the data to update

```
    protected void ASPxTreeList1_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxTreeList.TreeListCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        string[] rowKey = e.Argument.Split('|');

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbname"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            string query = "DELETE FROM Table WHERE id=@id";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowKey[0]);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }

        }
        GridFrom.DeleteRow(int.Parse(rowKey[2])); //rowKey[2] is the visibleIndex
        GridFrom.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing `GridFrom.DataBind();` because not all data sources support delete method. Are you sure that the file has been deleted in database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it requires refreshing of the page for the data to update

You don't see grid changes, because **ONLY** ASPxTreeList is updated during **ITS OWN** callback.

As a possible solution, disable ASPxTreeList's callbacks or delete a grid row using the grid's CustomCallback instead (in a similar manner).

```
<dx:ASPxTreeList ID="ASPxTreeList1" runat="server" EnableCallbacks="false">
</dx:ASPxTreeList>
```

Check the [The concept of callbacks - Why is it impossible to update external control data during a callback to another control](https://www.devexpress.com/kbid=KA18609) learning guide regarding this.